# Rails: Param is missing or the value is empty: discussion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

Discussion belong to project. When I try and edit a discussion I get the following error. `param is missing or the value is empty: discussion` on the following piece of code in the discussions_controller:

```
def discussion_params
    params.require(:discussion).permit(:title, :description)
end
```

I can't see what is wrong with that though. Is there something wrong with my routing or am I missing something?

discussions_controller.rb

```
class DiscussionsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :find_project, expect: [:destroy]

  def new
    @discussion = Discussion.new
  end

  def create
    @discussion = @project.discussions.build(discussion_params)
    if @discussion.save
      redirect_to new_project_discussion_path(@project)
    end
  end

  def edit
    @discussions = @project.discussions.find(discussion_params)
  end

  def update

    if @discussions.update_attributes(discussion_params)
      redirect_to new_project_discussion_path
    else
      render "edit"
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @discussions.destroy
    redirect_to new_project_discussion_path
  end


  private

  def discussion_params
    params.require(:discussion).permit(:title, :description)
  end

  def find_project
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
  end

end
```

projects_controller.rb

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @projects = Project.all
  end

  def show


  end

  def new
    @projects = Project.new

  end

  def create #no view
    @projects = Project.new(project_params)
    if @projects.save
      redirect_to projects_path, :notice => "Your project was sent!"
    else 
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def edit
    @projects = Project.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update #no view
    @projects = Project.find(params[:id])

    if @projects.update_attributes(project_params)
      redirect_to projects_path, :notice => "Your project has been updated."
    else
      render "edit"
    end
  end

  def destroy #no view
    @projects = Project.find(params[:id])
    @projects.destroy
    redirect_to projects_path, :notice => "Your project has been deleted."
  end

  private
  def project_params
    params.require(:project).permit(:title, :description)
  end


end
```

(discussions) _form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for [@project, @discussion] do |f| %>
  <div class="container">

    Project: <%= @project.title %> <%= link_to "Go back?", projects_path %> 
    <hr>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :title %>
      <%= f.text_field :title, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :description %>
      <%= f.text_area :description, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.submit "Submit discussion", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

(discussions) edit.html.erb

```
<%= render "form" %>
```

(discussions) new.html.erb

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="page-header">
    <h1>Discussions<small> Discuss the project.</small></h1>
  </div>
</div>


<%= render "form" %>


<% if !@project.discussions.blank? %>
  <% for item in @project.discussions %>
  <div class="container">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <%= item.title %>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
  <p>
    <%= item.description %> <br>
    <%= link_to "Comment", new_discussion_comment_path(item) %>
    <%= link_to "Delete", item, :method => :delete %> 
    <%= link_to "Edit", edit_project_discussion_path(@project, item) %> |
  </p>
  </div>
  </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

And here are my routes for both discussions and projects.

```
project_discussions GET    /projects/:project_id/discussions(.:format)             discussions#index
                         POST   /projects/:project_id/discussions(.:format)             discussions#create
  new_project_discussion GET    /projects/:project_id/discussions/new(.:format)         discussions#new
 edit_project_discussion GET    /projects/:project_id/discussions/:id/edit(.:format)    discussions#edit
      project_discussion GET    /projects/:project_id/discussions/:id(.:format)         discussions#show
                         PATCH  /projects/:project_id/discussions/:id(.:format)         discussions#update
                         PUT    /projects/:project_id/discussions/:id(.:format)         discussions#update
                         DELETE /projects/:project_id/discussions/:id(.:format)         discussions#destroy
                projects GET    /projects(.:format)                                     projects#index
                         POST   /projects(.:format)                                     projects#create
             new_project GET    /projects/new(.:format)                                 projects#new
            edit_project GET    /projects/:id/edit(.:format)                            projects#edit
                 project GET    /projects/:id(.:format)                                 projects#show
                         PATCH  /projects/:id(.:format)                                 projects#update
                         PUT    /projects/:id(.:format)                                 projects#update
                         DELETE /projects/:id(.:format)                                 projects#destroy
```

Comment: What params are actually posted (from your server logs)? Right now, the discussion key is missing.

Comment: Hm, when I click edit I get this message in the terminal. `ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: discussion):
  app/controllers/discussions_controller.rb:38:in 'discussion_params'
  app/controllers/discussions_controller.rb:17:in 'edit'`

Comment: can you install the pry debugger gem and put a binding.pry before the params.require ?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

> when I click edit I get this message in the terminal.
>   ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is
>   empty: discussion): app/controllers/discussions_controller.rb:38:in
>   'discussion_params' app/controllers/discussions_controller.rb:17:in
>   'edit'

The reason behind the error is in your `edit` method of your `discussions_controller.rb` you have this line

```
@discussions = @project.discussions.find(discussion_params)
```

you need to change it to

```
@discussion = Discussion.find(params[:id])
```

And also change your update action to the below.

```
def update
  @discussion = Discussion.find(params[:id])
   if @discussion.update_attributes(discussion_params)
     redirect_to new_project_discussion_path
   else
     render "edit"
   end
end
```